# Swizzle method for all subclases

Tags: ios, objective-c, swizzling

I have `CLLocationManager` class with method `setDelegate:`. Also I have inheritance classes in closed frameworks. I want to exchange implementation `setDelegate:` for this class and all inheritance.

```
NSArray *sfl_classGetSubclasses(Class parentClass) {
    int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
    Class *classes = NULL;

    classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        Class superClass = classes[i];
        do {
            superClass = class_getSuperclass(superClass);
        } while(superClass && superClass != parentClass);

        if (superClass == nil) {
            continue;
        }

        [result addObject:classes[i]];
    }
    free(classes);
    return result;
}

@implementation CLLocationManager (SimulateFakeLocations)

+ (void)initialize {
    [self swizzleSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) class1:self withSelector:@selector(sfl_setDelegate:) class2:self];
    NSArray *subclasses = sfl_classGetSubclasses(self); // I get empty array
    for (Class cl in subclasses) {
        [self swizzleSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) class1:cl withSelector:@selector(sfl_setDelegate:) class2:self];
    }
}

+ (void)swizzleSelector:(SEL)sel1 class1:(Class)class1 withSelector:(SEL)sel2 class2:(Class)class2
{
    Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class1, sel1);
    Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class2, sel2);

    BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class1,
                                        sel1,
                                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

    if (didAddMethod) {
        class_replaceMethod(class2,
                            sel2,
                            method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                            method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
    } else {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
    }
}
// ...
@end
```

But I do not get any subclasses `sfl_classGetSubclasses`. This is first problem. Second: I know the name of subclass, and I try to exchange method  in inhered class.

```
Class cl = NSClassFromString(@"YMKLocationManager");
[self swizzleSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) class1:cl withSelector:@selector(sfl_setDelegate:) class2:self];
```

But application is fall in runtime. Until I have use closed frameworks, exchange methods works perfectly.

Comment: @luk2302 This code will not use for AppStore submition. This for simulate track location. With google maps works perfectly.